# unexpected argument '--ws-port' found

Tags: substrate-node-template, relay-chain, substrate-node

I am preparing local relay chain from [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/#start-the-relay-chain-node). Configure polkadot and added `raw-local-chainspec.json` file but while running first validator, it gives this error.

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot % ./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain /tmp/raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
error: unexpected argument '--ws-port' found

  tip: a similar argument exists: '--workers-path'

Usage: polkadot --alice --validator --port <PORT> --workers-path <PATH> <--chain <CHAIN_SPEC>|--dev|--base-path <PATH>|--log <LOG_PATTERN>...|--detailed-log-output|--disable-log-color|--enable-log-reloading|--tracing-targets <TARGETS>|--tracing-receiver <RECEIVER>>

For more information, try '--help'.
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air polkadot %
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion, always checking the release detail before using/upgrading to it: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.43

```
CLI changes
This release removes the following CLI parameters:

--rpc-max-payload (replaced by --rpc-max-request-size and --rpc-max-response-size)
--ws-max-out-buffer-capacity
--ws-external (replaced by --rpc-external)
--unsafe-ws-external (replaced by --unsafe-rpc-external)
--ipc--path
--ws-port (replaced by --rpc-port)
--ws-max--connections (replaced by --rpc-max-connections)
--rpc-http (replaced by --rpc-addr)
--rpc-ws (replaced by --rpc-addr)
```

Comment: I am facing error in opening spec file. `Error: 
   0: Invalid input: Error opening spec file /tmp/raw-local-chainspec.json: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

Comment: even though there is [file in that directory](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15FleOv_kudt5Ks7OsLYS1_FC32ipU6rX/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: @Ganesh11 /tmp is different from the one in your current project directory. /tmp is associated to the file systems.

Answer (score 2):

--ws-port is replaced by --rpc-port. You can confirm this from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13384)